# How to write test to cross-check data in selenium-javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I have to check if data inserted in the web element is right or not, how can i do it using selenium-webdriver in javascript.

I want result of one of the function that i wrote somewhere else, how to get it. (This function is fetching some data from web using axios)

*Test.js*

```js
const assert = require('assert');
const { Builder, WebDriver } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { someFunction } = require('../react/services/someFunction');
```

*ApiService.js*

```js
export async function someFunction(pid, val) {
  const response = await axiosInstance.put(
    `/${pid}`,
    val
  );
  return response.data;
}
```

**Error**:

```
import axios from 'axios';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: You can simply use assert, however, we would need a bit more information on this ticket. Update the question with relevant HTML, code/error if any.